# In log4j2.properties, not able to read property from tomcat context.xml

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, pom.xml, log4j2

I am trying to read properties from tomcat server context.xml to my log4j2.properties. I tried using {sys:} {env:} and also searched but no luck.

log4j2.properties

```
appender.email=org.apache.net.SMTPAppender
appender.email.type=smtp
appender.email.name = Email
appender.email.SMTPHost=${env:log4j.smtpHost}
appender.email.From=${env:log4j.emailAddress}
appender.email.BufferSize=512
appender.email.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.email.layout.Pattern=[%x%d{ISO8601}]%n%n%-5p%n%n%c%n%n%m%M%n%n
```

I am not able to read property **${env:log4j.smtpHost}** OR **${env:log4j.emailAddress}** it's printing as it is in log.

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

> using exclusions with all spring boot dependency

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

context.xml

```
<Environment name="log4j.smtpHost" override="false"
    type="java.lang.String" value="testsmtp" />

<Environment name="log4j.emailAddress"
    override="false" type="java.lang.String" value="test@gmail" />
```

Please let me know how to read this into log4j2 property OR any other solution to make SMTP property configurable.

Comment: I tried with application.properties but no luck

Comment: is it  dependency issue ?

Answer (score 0):

We are reading property of context.xml in java and setting it to Sysytem properties.

```
System.setProperty("log4j.smtpHost", read from context.xml)
```

and then reading it in log4j2.properties.

> appender.email.SMTPHost=${sys:log4j.smtpHost}

Hope this will help others.